# Shared data in functional programming

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have been working on a project in JavaScript which requires a data structure (read only), to be shared between two functions.

```
var mySharedData = ['hours', 'minutes', 'seconds'];
```

Now I have two functions that need access to this (static) read only data structure.

```
var sampleFunction1 = function(userSuppliedData) {
    //map over user data applying mySharedData to it
};

var sampleFunction2 = function(userSuppliedData) {
    //reduce user data also accessing mySharedData
};
```

Since this is JavaScript and both functions are in the same scope I could just "cheat" and leverage the bad scoping of var and access the shared data in both functions but I don't feel like this is the proper way of doing it.

I also considered currying both functions and just passing the shared data as the first argument like so:

```
var mySharedData = ['hours', 'minutes', 'seconds'];

var sampleFunction1 = _.curry(function(sharedData, userSuppliedData) {
    //map over user data applying sharedData to it
})(mySharedData);

var sampleFunction2 = _.curry(function(sharedData, userSuppliedData) {
    //reduce user data also accessing sharedData
})(mySharedData);
```

What is the recommended way of sharing data between functions? Should this even be done in functional programming or am I making my functions impure with shared data structures?

Comment: The shared data would be common to both [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29)

Comment: So you suggest doing something like this?
`function() {
    //now I'm in a closure
    var mySharedData = ['hours', 'minutes', 'seconds'];
    var sampleFunction1 = function(userSuppliedData) {
        //map over user data applying mySharedData to it
    };

    var sampleFunction2 = function(userSuppliedData) {
        //reduce user data also accessing mySharedData
    };
}`

Comment: Every user function is implemented as a closure in Javascript

Comment: Why would you consider using the closure as cheating?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `mySharedData` is private for both closures:

```
(function (context) {
    var mySharedData = ['hours', 'minutes', 'seconds'];

    context.sampleFunction1 = function (userSuppliedData) {
        //map over user data applying mySharedData to it
        // mySharedData....
    };

    context.sampleFunction2 = function (userSuppliedData) {
        //reduce user data also accessing mySharedData
        // mySharedData....
    };
})(this);
```

If `mySharedData` is public:

```
var mySharedData = ['hours', 'minutes', 'seconds'];

var sampleFunction1 = function (userSuppliedData) {
    //map over user data applying mySharedData to it
    // mySharedData...
};

var sampleFunction2 = function (userSuppliedData) {
    //reduce user data also accessing mySharedData
    // mySharedData...
};
```

If what you need is that `mySharedData` can not be edited:

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'mySharedData', {
    get: function () {
        return ['hours', 'minutes', 'seconds'];
    }
});

console.log(mySharedData);
// ['hours', 'minutes', 'seconds']

mySharedData.push('foo');
mySharedData[1] = 'bar';

console.log(mySharedData);
// ['hours', 'minutes', 'seconds']
```

Answer (score -2):

Use it any way you want.

Using an immutable constant from two functions is not in any way problematic or impure.

A problem arises if one of the functions mutates the value. In JS this can be prevented by declaring the binding with `const` and by using `Object.freeze` to make the value immutable.

Comment: I added some details, if the downvoters wish to explain their view it would be interesting for me.